# Having issues appending text to Summernote element on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I am using summernote for wysiwyg editor. I am trying to append text to the selected element.

I have tried to append the text to the .note-editable that is created by the summernote script with no luck

```
<script>
  $('#selector').on('change', function () {

    let currentTemplate = 'This will come from db';

    $('.note-editable').html(currentTemplate);

    $('#email_body').summernote();
  });
 </script>
```

On change, the wysiwyg editor should be filled with the text from db. This will update every time a different selection is made.

Comment: Shouldn't you set the html content after initialising summernote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your code like this:

```
$('#selector').on('change', function () { let currentTemplate = 
'This will come from db'; 
$('#email_body').summernote(); 
$('.note- editable').html(currentTemplate);});
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying is wrong. you need to get the content using the following code.

change this

```
$('#email_body').summernote();
```

to

```
$('#email_body').summernote('code');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the html code for summernote

code - get the HTML source code underlying the text in the editor:

```
$('#email_body').summernote('code');
```